# Auhtorizing Azure subscription in VSTS fails

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to add a release to VSTS. Our VSTS is backed by Azure AD and I have logged in with the account that is the admin of the Azure subscription to which I want to deploy the release. I can see the Azure subscription in the dropdown but when I click Authorize I get the following error popup.

[image]

Comment: Is your account also admin of the azure ad itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the authentication pop-up window has been blocked, turn pop-up blocker off or change another browser and try again.

[Change security and privacy settings for Internet Explorer 11](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/17479/windows-internet-explorer-11-change-security-privacy-settings)

On the other hand, you also can manual configure the azure service endpoint, refer to this article below (manual configuration section)

[Automating Azure Resource Group deployment using a Service Principal in Visual Studio Online: Build/Release Management](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/04/automating-azure-resource-group-deployment-using-a-service-principal-in-visual-studio-online-buildrelease-management/)

Comment: I was the popup blocker. Additionally when I went over to Settings/Services/Endpoints the error message also stated that I need to be in the Endpoint Creators -group.